# How do you use bit shift operators to find out a certain digit of a number in base 2 using python?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I've been trying to solve this and the instructions said that it is possible to do so using bit shift and bit wise operators but I can't seem to come close to a solution.

```
The nth bit of an integer is the value of the nth place value of a number 
that's written in base 2.
```

What I understood from that is when you take a number, for example 4, it's base 2 representation would be 100. Because it asks for the place value and not the position, I think the first bit would be the one on the far right, so that would be 0. The second bit would be 0, and the third bit would be 1.

```
Given two integers a,b where a<=10**9 and 2**b<=a, write a code that checks 
whether the bth bit is on (or equal to 1). If it is on, print out 'On', 
otherwise, print 'Off'.
```

So far this is what I have but I know it's no where near what I'm actually supposed to be doing.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
base2b = bin(b) #i don't even think this function exists
stringB = str(base2b)
call = stringB[-b] #-b because I started counting from the right
if call == 1:
    print ('On')
else:
    print('Off')
```

We were required to use bit shift or bit wise operators but as you can see, my sad code does not contain any of those. 
This is what the input and output is supposed to look like:

```
Sample Input:
4 3
Sample Output:
On
```

Can anyone can tell me how exactly I'm supposed to find an nth digit of that same number in its base 2 form? (or is that even the right question?) I think a better (although vaguer) question would be how do I go about solving this code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Start with a 1, shift it left a few places until it matches the place you want (n - 1, because it's already in the first place, so to get to the third place it needs to move two places, not three).

```
00001110    # 14 - input number
00000001    # 1 start with 1.
            # << shift it over to the nth place (3rd place)
00000100

            # AND the original with this. 
00000100    # a number if it was set in both, 0 if it wasn't.
```

Bitwise AND the original number with the 1 in the chosen place.

```
def nth_bit(number, position):
    state = number & (1 << position - 1)

    print('On' if state else 'Off')
```

Answer (score 0):

In python as in most languages, the bit shift operator `<<` and `>>` shift the number's binary representation. For instance `13`'s binary representation is `1101`. Shifting it to the left will give `11010` which is `26` and shifting to the right gives `110` which is `6`.

If you want to access the nth digit in the binary representation, one way is to do:

```
# The following function simply accesses the last bit
def last_bit(number): 
    return number - (number >> 1 << 1) 

# Once we have shifted a number, the last bit is the one we are looking for
def nth_bit(number,position):
    return last_bit(number >> position)
```

Note: `last_bit` is kind of an overkill since it could be done using `number%2`, but you asked for a solution using bitwise operations.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry this answer is long, and needs more paragraph breaks.  But read it anyway, because it's the only one (so far) that tries to answer your "vague" question.

The funny thing is, the `bin` function actually does exist!  And it does almost exactly what you want.  (It sticks a `0b` in front, but since you count from the right, it doesn't matter.)

Part of getting good at programming (and other things) is developing a good grab bag of tricks.  (Some say it's a big part, others say it's a small part, but it's definitely a part.)  If you do enough exercises like this, bitwise operators will eventually become part of your bag.  You'll be able to look at problem for a few seconds, think to yourself "This smells like it can be solved with bit shifts" and five minutes later you'll have a working solution.

It's even more important to have a bag of "meta-tricks".  This bag is usually much smaller, but very useful.  The biggest compartment in the bag of meta-tricks is labeled "what to try when I don't know how to do it".  I can see from your question that you already have at least two such tricks in this compartment.  I think the first trick you used is "how would I do it without a computer?".  I personally use this one A LOT.  You thought: if someone gave me a number written in binary and asked for the `n`th digit, I would count the digits until I reached `n`.  Good job!  Then you translated this into code, but not quite right.  You wanted to use check if the `b`th bit of `a` is on, but you instead checked the `b`th bit of `b`.  Oops :)

But of course, this doesn't use bitwise operators.  So then you used a second trick: ask for help!  I also use this one A LOT.  I think I've asked way more questions on this site than I've answered.  And it worked: you got two ways to code this up, and you're about to get a third.

I will now give you two more tricks for your "meta-trick" bag.  You may already know these, but if so it looks like you forgot to apply this one:

SOLVE AN EASY CASE (the easier the better)

Picking a good special case to start with can require a bit of intuition and/or trial and error, but here it's not too hard to see that the easy case here is when you're asked for the least significant bit.  (Fun fact: this is the bit that tells you if the number is even or odd.  Obvious once someone mentions it, but sometimes not earlier.)  So how to do that?  It's a bit tricky using just bit shifts.  (Flynsee managed to do it; see his `last_bit` function.)  But presumably you're allowed to use the other bitwise operations, and if you've read TessellatingHeckler's answer you already know what bitwise operation he used, other than shifts.  If you haven't read it, this is a good chance to challenge yourself.  Don't read the next sentence until you've thought for a few seconds.  A minute or two would be even better.  Maybe I should even use a "spoiler" tag?  Nah.  Okay, that's enough, the perfect bitwise operator here is bitwise and.  In particular, `number&1` will tell you if a number is even or odd.  (If this is not obvious, stop and think for a few minutes until you see why.)

We're now ready for the second trick:

TURN THE HARD CASES INTO EASY ONES

This is not always possible, but it's often worth trying.  Here, we can approach the problem like this: I have a way to get the last bit (or first bit depending which side you count from), but I want the `b`th bit.  If there was only some way to move the `b`th bit into the position I want.  But all these other stupid bits are in my way.  I wish I could get rid of them somehow.  Wait a minute... I want to move the `b`th bit?  Move?  Also known as shift?  Hm...

I'll let you solve the rest of it now :)  I hope this at least partly answers your "vague" question

Comment: if you can tell, i'm kind of new to this so everything i encounter still needs a lot of explaining, so thanks for explaining it! :)

Comment: And thank you for letting me know you read it :)  I was starting to think that was all for nothing.